# How do you exclude all QToolTips from the Qt global stylesheet selector?

Tags: qt, tooltip, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I have a global stylesheet selector (the '*' block) which changes font properties for all Qt widgets in the application. However, that also affects QToolTip - not desired. How do you exclude QToolTip from being affected by the global selector? I couldn't find a stylesheet operator for exclusion.

I can of course not use the global selector and copy the shared styles for every possible widget type. Obviously this is cumbersome, not scalable, clutters the QSS and may not provide full coverage. I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: So what with my answer? Is it helpful? I didn't get any feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that doesn't address my specific issue. Also, my original question was a bit ambiguous. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line:

```
QToolTip{}
```

Should reset the QToolTip style to default.

Answer (score 1):

`QToolTip` uses font from widget. You apply another font to widget so this font applies also to tooltip. To avoid this try to use `html` tooltip:

```
ui->lineEdit->setToolTip("<font face =\"aharoni\">test</font>");
ui->lineEdit->setText("test");
```

Result with `aharoni` font (for better visual comparison):

[image]

with `*{font-family:consolas}` stylesheet.